# Matlab output array to excel or other file format with specific name

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab, csv

I have a directory of excel files that I need to read into Matlab as an array, transpose the array and then export back to an excel file. The excel file arrays are 32626 x 153 so I don't think I can output to an excel file first. I was thinking of outputting to a `*.txt` or `*.csv` file then opening it in excel. The current code I have written is trying to write to a `*.csv` file

I need the name of the output file to include part of the name of the input file. For example, the input file name is `data.xlsx` and I need the name of the ouyput file to be  `data_transposed.csv`.

The following is the code I have already written to read the `*.xlsx` files in the directory and save the data to an array, then transpose the array, then write the transposed array to a `*.csv` file.

```
files = dir('*.xlsx');
for i = 1:length(files)
    filename = files(i).name;
    [path, name, extention] = fileparts(filename);
    array = xlsread(filename);
    transposearray = transpose(array);
    csvwrite('outputfile.csv' , transposearray)
end
```

There are a few issues with this code:

1. The output file name is `'outputfile'` rather than part of the `'inputfilename_transpose'` as I need it to be. (see explanation above)
2. The output file name is `'outputfile'` rather than part of the `'inputfilename_transpose'` as I need it to be. (see explanation above)
   This code only writes the first `*.xlsx` file in the directory to the output file. I know the loop is iterating over all the `*.xlsx` files in the directory because, when I take the semi-colons off all the other lines and comment out the `csvwrite` line, Matlab is ingesting the correct information.

EDIT:
The code below works to output a file for every input file as well as include the input file name in the output file name

```
files = dir('*.xlsx');
for i = 1:length(files)
    filename = files(i).name;
    [path, name, extention] = fileparts(filename);
    array = xlsread(filename);
    transposearray = transpose(array);
    csvwrite(['outputfile',name,'.csv'] , transposearray)
end
```

Excel still will not read the output file as it has double the number of columns excel can open. How can I parse out the first half of the transposed columns into sheet 1 and the second half of the transposed columns into sheet 2 of the same excel workbook? I assume this means I now have to use `xlswrite()` instead of `csvwrite()`.

EDIT: There are too many columns of excel to read the file. Therefore, I must parse the data into two separate sheets in one worksheet. 
The first xlswrite needs to take the first 16,384 columns (with all 153 rows) and place the values in excel sheet 1 starting at A1.
The second xlswrite needs to take column number 16,385 to the last column (with all 153 rows) and place the values in excel sheet 2 starting at A1.
How do I do this?

Comment: Regarding your edit: You need to break up the array you're exporting. Exporting the full array to two separate sheets isn't going to do you any more good than the full array on one sheet. You don't have to specify a range of cells to export to in excel, specify your data range and sheet. If you don't specify a range, it starts at A1 by default. Read [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code writes all the files in the directory all of then has the same name they are getting overwritten. Try this

```
files = dir('*.xlsx');
for i = 1:length(files)
    filename = files(i).name;
    [path, name, extention] = fileparts(filename);
    array = xlsread(filename);
    transposearray = transpose(array);
    csvwrite([path,'\',name,'_transpose','.csv'] , transposearray)
end
```

Beware that `dir` reads files in the order as given by OS which **may not be always sorted by name** even if you have sorted your files by name while viewing them in a folder

For **EDIT** part

```
files = dir('*.xlsx');
for i = 1:length(files)
    filename = files(i).name;
    [path, name, extention] = fileparts(filename);
    array = xlsread(filename);
    transposearray = transpose(array);
    n  = ceil(size(transposearray,2)/2);
    transportarray_part1 = transposearray(:,1:n);
    transposearray _part2 = transposearray(:,n+1:end);
    xlswrite([path,'\',name,'_transpose','.csv'], transposearray_part1,1);
    xlswrite([path,'\',name,'_transpose','.csv'], transposearray_part2,2);
end
```

Comment: It's generally better practice to utilize `fullfile` (or `filesep` at the very least) instead of manually specifying a file separator to avoid OS compatibility issues.

Comment: great that worked! Now the only issue is that there are more columns than excel can support - there are actually double the columns. Is there anyway to output half the transposed columns to one excel sheet and the other half to a second excel sheet? I assume this means i have to use xslxwrite() instead.

Comment: @user3736288 Yes, by using [`xlswrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) you can break up the data however you want and specify a sheet to write each block to. See the examples in the documentation for the syntax.

Comment: it seems the range part of xlswrite is to specify the specific cell in excel, not the specific data to write to excel

Comment: Yes, [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) I already linked tells you that and gives you the syntax to use.

Comment: from my understanding that xlrange is the range of cells to place the data, not a way to parse out the data then place it. When i try to use it, it doesn't work

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the n=ceil(size)) line? It works but i don't understand what that line is doing

Comment: that is calculating the least integer of "half of the number of columns" of B. `ceil` function gives least integer of a number. It is used so as if "half of number of columns" is not even ,still `n` would remain an integer.